# Why do I get a ValueError when trying to split a line of input and assign to multiple variables?

Tags: python

I tried some code like this to read question and answer pairs from a file:

```
questions_list = []
answers_list = []

with open('qanda.txt', 'r') as questions_file:
    for line in questions_file:
        line = line.strip()
        questions, answers = line.split(':')
        questions_list.append(questions)
        answers_list.append(answers)
```

But sometimes I get an exception from the `questions, answers = line.split(':')` line, that says:

(Python 2.x)
`builtins.ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack`

(Python 3.x)
`ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`

Alternatively, the opposite problem:
`ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`

Why does this occur? How can I fix or work around the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is probably because when you're doing the splitting, there is no `:`, so the function just returns one argument, and not 2. This is probably caused by the last line, meaning that you're last line has nothing but empty spaces. Like so:

```
>>> a = '   '
>>> a = a.strip()
>>> a
''
>>> a.split(':')
['']
```

As you can see, the list returned from `.split` is just a single empty string. So, just to show you a demo, this is a sample file:

> ```
> a: b
> c: d
> e: f
>
> g: h
> ```

We try to use the following script (`val.txt` is the name of the above file):

```
with open('val.txt', 'r') as v:
    for line in v:
        a, b = line.split(':')
        print a, b
```

And this gives us:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
a  b

c  d
  File "C:/Nafiul Stuff/Python/testingZone/28_11_13/val.py", line 3, in <module>

    a, b = line.split(':')
e  f
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

When trying to look at this through a debugger, the variable `line` becomes `\n`, and you can't split that.

However, a simple logical ammendment, would correct this problem:

```
with open('val.txt', 'r') as v:
    for line in v:
        if ':' in line:
            a, b = line.strip().split(':')
            print a, b
```

Comment: thanks for replies..my first line in the file was as follows     what command displays the amount of memory available:free  ...i will try the code above soon and see what happens, thanks

Comment: @user3046660 If this answer helped you, please feel free to upvote it, and if it answered your question, please accept it by clicking the tickmark on the left hand side of this question.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
question, answers = line.split(':', maxsplit=1)
question, __, answers = line.partition(':')
```

Also in Python 3 you can do something else:

```
question, *many_answers = line.split(':')
```

which looks like:

```
temp = line.split(':')
question = temp[0]
many_answers = tuple(temp[1:])
```

Comment: The `.partition` suggestion is good, but supplying `maxsplit` to the `.split` method will only fix the case where there are too *many* items in the input, not too few.

Answer (score 3):

`line.split(':')` apparently returns a list with one element, not two.

Hence that's why it can't unpack the result into `questions` and `answers`. Example:

```
>>> line = 'this-line-does-not-contain-a-colon'
>>> question, answers = line.split(':')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens could be a few, as already covered in the other answers. Empty line, or maybe a line only have a question and no colon. If you want to parse the lines even if they don't have the colon (for example if some lines only have the question), you can change your split to the following:

```
questions, answers, garbage = (line+'::').split(':', maxsplit=2)
```

This way, the values for `questions` and `answers` will be filled if they are there, and will be empty if the original file doesn't have them. For all intents and purposes, ignore the variable `garbage`.

Comment: It will be more elegant to "pad" the list with extra elements *after* the split call; then there is no `garbage` to discard. By padding and then slicing, the `maxsplit` argument becomes unnecessary.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel your comment doesn't make any sense. I added the padding so that we can split without error. If we already did the split, what would you pad it for? Besides, if you don't pad before splitting, you get the error that OP is getting and doesn't want; the very purpose of padding is to be able to split without errors.

Comment: It's quite simple: split without a limit, pad *the list* with *empty* elements, slice it to the appropriate length, *then* unpack.

Comment: That's one step lengthier, and more convoluted IMHO. I don't agree it would be more elegant, to me it's the opposite. ;) But it is a different solution, so feel free to post your own answer. ^_^