# Getting ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, valueerror

I get this error :

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\mukab\PycharmProjects\miniproject5\main.py", line 43, in 
> view()
>
> File "C:\Users\mukab\PycharmProjects\miniproject5\main.py", line 25, in view
> user,passw = data.split("|",1)
>
> ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1).

when I run my code. I don't know where am going wrong.

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

'''
def write_key():
    key = Fernet.generate_key()
    with open("key.key","wb") as key_file:
        key_file.write(key)'''

def load_key():
    file = open("key.key","rb")
    key = file.read()
    file.close()
    return key


key = load_key()
fer = Fernet(key)


def view():
    with open('passwords.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            data = line.rstrip()
            user,passw = data.split("|",1)
            print("User:",user, " |Password:", fer.decrypt(passw.encode()).decode())

def create():
    name = input("Account Name: \n")
    password = input("Enter password \n")

    with open('passwords.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(name + " : " + fer.encrypt(password.encode()).decode() + "\n")


while True:
    mode = input("Would you like to view existing password or create a new password? press Q for quit\n").lower()
    if mode == "q":
        break

    if mode == "view":
        view()
    elif mode == "create":
        create()
    else:
        print("Invalid mode")
        continue
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get a ValueError when trying to split a line of input and assign to multiple variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20270871/why-do-i-get-a-valueerror-when-trying-to-split-a-line-of-input-and-assign-to-mul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is apparently this line:

```
            user,passw = data.split("|",1)
```

The error means that when calling `split`, one value has been returned which you try to assign to two values: `user, passw`.

Check this simplified example for comparison:

```
>>> "banana".split("|")
['banana']                      # returned one value
>>> "banana|".split("|")
['banana', '']                  # returned two values
```

One way to handle that would be to assign the output to one single value and then check what the split method actually returned:

```
            credentials = data.split("|", 1)
            if len(credentials) == 2:
                 user, passw = credentials
            else:
                print("this is not what I expected")
```